# Disable Intel(R) 82578DM Network Connector permanently

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter, connector

My computer, HP Compaq 8100 Elite CMT x64-based PC, running Microsoft Windows 7 Professional (64 bit) is equipped with an Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection which connects to the Motorola Router provided by the Internet provider.  The connection works fine and is on all-the-time.

For security reason, I want to disable this *Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection* permanently, so the machine is not connected to the Internet. Reconnecting to the Internet is done by manually enabling the connection. Until a few weeks ago, this task could be easily performed by simply disabling the Internet connection. Since then, the unit can be disabled but comes up immediately again.  The drivers for this unit are up-to-date (according to the built in driver check; Driver Version 12.10.13.0). Power Management is off for "turn off" and "wake the computer".

The connection which uses this Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection uses the following items:

- Client for Microsoft Networks
- Symantec Network Security Intermediate Filter Driver
- File and Printer sharing for Microsoft Networks
- QoS Packet Scheduler
- Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver
- Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder
- Pure Networks Device Discovery Driver
- Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)
- Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)

The Internet Protocols (TCP/IPv4, TCP/IPv6) obtain IP address and DNS server address automatically. No special advanced settings are defined, I think standard settings are ok.

I assume that a switch has been changed that requests the immediate enabling of this Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection device. But I am unable to locate this switch.

On other computers in my network, hooked to the same router, disabling the Internet connection works fine. They have the same setup for the connections.

I checked many entries in this forum but did not find a decent answer. Thus any suggestion for resolving the issue is welcome.

Problem is solved by reloading an earlier system configuration from Backup-Device.
However, cause of the problem could not be identified.
None of the suggestions provided a solution.

**Case is closed**.

Comment: Can you clarify *precisely* what it is you are doing when you say you "disable the Internet connection".

Comment: Classical named Network Connection "xxxx" in Windows (Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections), use the switch/button "disable", connection goes off, as expected but comes back immediately

Comment: If you say “Case closed”, please answer your own question and mark it as resolved after the wait time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable the Ethernet Adapter with Powershell:

- This will disable all Network Adapters
- If you want to disable only a specific network Adapter change the * with the AdapterName

This is the cmd:
    powershell.exe -Command {Disable-NetAdapter -Name "*" -Confirm:$false}

The Powershell Command is:

- Disable-NetAdapter -Name "*" -Confirm:$false

Answer (score 0):

Disable the network adapter in Device Manager. Failing that: if the NIC is on-board you should be able to disable it in BIOS. You could also enable MAC filtering on your router to only allow devices you want to permit access.